# How do I save ALL the cookies from a specific Site using curl or wget

Tags: bash, authentication, cookies, curl, wget

Basically I am trying to do specific things on a certain website. The first thing I want to do is login and save the cookies which I have done successfully with something like this:

```
    curl "http://site/login" --data "email=email" --data "password=password" --cookie "cookies.txt" --cookie-jar "cookies.txt" --location > login.html
```

however this method of storing the cookies only gives me fields such as **kayla** and djcs_route.
But this site has other fields that I need such as **djcs_session** and **s_vnum**. The cookie that I saved using the method above doesn't save these fields. When I go onto the google chrome cookies, I can see all of these fields. So my question is, is there a way to obtain all the fields.

I've attached a picture of the cookie fields that I want.
[image]
Is there a way to obtain the contents of the cookies and save it to a text file?

I AM NOT trying to extract cookies from the Chrome broswer, I am trying to emulate what it does and save all the session cookies to cookies.txt using curl

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of a programming question, so it might be more appropriate on some other site, maybe on Unix & Linux or Super User. That said, the reason why your cookies.txt does not contain all cookies is that Chrome does not store temporary session cookies which form a major part of your 18 cookies there on disk.

You can use any of available third party cookie manager extensions to Chrome to export those session cookies to a text file.

Comment: well no im trying to emulate what a browser does with its cookies. I want these session cookies to be stored in cookies.txt but I only send up with certain temporary session cookies. When i do  `curl "http://site/login" --data "email=email" --data "password=password" --cookie "cookies.txt" --cookie-jar "cookies.txt" --location > login.html` it saves only 2 of the cookies listed above. I am asking how to I get the rest of the cookies using curl. I am not trying to extract it from Chrome, I am trying to get cookies remotely